# Pivot point will not move in edit mode when moving mesh, in object mode only pivot point moves not the mesh

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

I am a beginner in Blender.

My pivot point suddenly looked odd. It has an y, x, y axis on it. When in Object mode the mesh refuse to move when I grab it with 'G'. When I am in Edit mode the pivot point refuse to move when I select and move the mesh.

[image: This is how the pivot point looks in object mode.]

[image: This is how it looks in edit mode.]

When I open a new project, the problem dosen't persist. So it is something I've done with this file.

Is it possible to turn back to a regular pivot point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've enabled the *Affect Only Origins* option, disable it:

[image]

Comment: I was slower this time, this same picture but with a red box :D

Comment: Sorry MikoCG, Blender Stack Exchange is like the wild west, you need to be fast  :/

Comment: @MikoCG [Life on the surface](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2815/60486)